# I wrote this few lines of code to change the xml file of this class but it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, onclicklistener

Im a Beginner in Java and Android Studio. With this Code I try to change the layout in this activity. The current layout is "marcelscorpion_1".
Only the Buttons "weiter_1" and "zurück_1" are working and I don't know why...

```
public void SwitchLayout()
{
    Button weiter_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_weiter1);
    Button zurück_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_zurück1);

    View marcelscorpion_2 = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.marcelscorpion_2, null);
    Button weiter_2 = (Button) marcelscorpion_2.findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_weiter2);
    Button zurück_2 = (Button) marcelscorpion_2.findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_zurück2);

    View marcelscorpion_3 = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.marcelscorpion_3, null);
    Button weiter_3 = (Button) marcelscorpion_3.findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_weiter3);
    Button zurück_3 = (Button) marcelscorpion_3.findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_zurück3);



    weiter_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_2);
        }
    });

    weiter_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_3);
        }
    });

    weiter_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_1);
        }
    });

    zurück_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_3);
        }
    });

    zurück_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_1);
        }
    });

    zurück_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_2);
        }
    });
}
```

Need Help ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `setContentView()` you should find and setOnClickListener(..) again to all buttons contained in the new layout.

A better way is define onclick attribute in the layouts xml file.
For instance if you have this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/w2"
    android:onClick="getms3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="w2" />
```

then you should define

```
public void getms3(View v) 
{
   setContentView(R.layout.ms3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your buttons of that layout when you are doing `setContentView()` in onClick() methods  like this :

```
weiter_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.marcelscorpion_2);
            Button weiter_2 = (Button) marcelscorpion_2.findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_weiter2);
Button zurück_2 = (Button) marcelscorpion_2.findViewById(R.id.marcelscorpion_zurück2);

        }
    });
```